# Reactjs application Azure deployment getting failed

Tags: reactjs, azure, npm, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy my reactjs application on Azure cloud platform. I have set git repo as deployment option/source. My deployment is getting failed. I am seeing a lot of npm errors. In the error log of azure I am getting this

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling node.js deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: '.idea\workspace.xml'
Copying file: 'node_modules\.bin\modernizr'
Copying file: 'node_modules\@trendmicro\react-toggle-switch\LICENSE'
Copying file: 'node_modules\@trendmicro\react-toggle-switch\package.json'
Copying file: 'node_modules\@trendmicro\react-toggle-switch\README.md'
Copying file: 'node_modules\@trendmicro\react-toggle-switch\dist\react-toggle-switch.css'
Copying file: 'node_modules\@trendmicro\react-toggle-switch\dist\react-toggle-switch.css.map'
Copying file: 'node_modules\@trendmicro\react-toggle-switch\dist\react-toggle-switch.min.css'
Copying file: 'node_modules\@trendmicro\react-toggle-switch\lib\index.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\@trendmicro\react-toggle-switch\lib\index.js.map'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bez\bower.json'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bez\jquery.bez.min.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bez\LICENSE.txt'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bez\Makefile'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bez\package.json'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bez\README.md'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bez\src\jquery.bez.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\CHANGELOG.md'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\Gruntfile.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\LICENSE'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\package.json'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\README.md'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap-theme.css'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap-theme.css.map'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap-theme.min.css'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap-theme.min.css.map'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css.map'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css.map'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\npm.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\grunt\.jshintrc'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\grunt\bs-commonjs-generator.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\grunt\bs-glyphicons-data-generator.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\grunt\bs-lessdoc-parser.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\grunt\bs-raw-files-generator.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\bootstrap\grunt\change-version.js'
Omitting next output lines...
Processed 485 files...
Processed 1008 files...
Processed 1393 files...
Processed 1755 files...
Using start-up script build/server-bundle.js from package.json.
Generated web.config.
Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.10.40, 0.12.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.6, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.3.0, 4.3.2, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.6, 4.4.7, 4.5.0, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.8.4, 5.0.0, 5.1.1, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.5.0, 5.6.0, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.8.0, 5.9.1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.2, 6.3.0, 6.5.0, 6.6.0, 6.7.0, 6.9.0, 6.9.1, 6.9.2, 6.9.4, 6.9.5, 6.10.0, 6.11.1, 6.11.2, 7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.2.0, 7.3.0, 7.4.0, 7.5.0, 7.6.0, 7.7.4, 7.10.0, 7.10.1, 8.0.0, 8.1.4, 8.4.0.
Selected node.js version 7.4.0. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
Selected npm version 3.9.5
Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\build\iisnode.yml

> react-bootstrap-select@0.14.0 postinstall D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\react-bootstrap-select
> jsx jsx/ dist/

'jsx' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
tessact@0.0.1 D:\home\site\wwwroot
+-- @trendmicro/react-toggle-switch@0.5.5 
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
+-- bez@0.1.0 
+-- bootstrap@3.3.7 
+-- bootstrap-select@1.12.4 
+-- bootstrap-slider@9.8.0 
+-- bootstrap-tagsinput@0.7.1  extraneous
+-- css-loader@0.23.1 
+-- ion-rangeslider@2.1.7  extraneous
+-- isotope-layout@3.0.4  extraneous
+-- jquery@3.2.1 
+-- jquery-bridget@2.0.1  extraneous
+-- jquery-unveil@1.3.2 
+-- jquery.actual@1.0.19 
+-- jquery.scrollbar@0.2.11 
+-- modernizr@3.5.0 
+-- nouislider@10.0.0 
+-- pace-js@1.0.2 
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.2
+-- rc-slider@8.0.2  extraneous
npm WARN react-addons-test-utils@15.6.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.4.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native@0.39.2 requires a peer of react@~15.4.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.3.2
npm WARN tessact@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\7.4.0\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\3.9.5\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! react-bootstrap-select@0.14.0 postinstall: `jsx jsx/ dist/`
+-- react-addons-test-utils@15.6.0 
npm ERR! Exit status 1
+-- react-custom-scrollbars@4.1.2 
npm ERR! 
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@15.3.2
npm ERR! Failed at the react-bootstrap-select@0.14.0 postinstall script 'jsx jsx/ dist/'.
+-- react-modal@2.2.4 
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
+-- react-nouislider@2.0.0 
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the react-bootstrap-select package,
+-- react-scrollbars@0.0.5 
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
+-- react-select2-datga-wrapper@0.0.8  extraneous
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
+-- react-select2-wrapper@1.0.4-beta5  extraneous
npm ERR!     jsx jsx/ dist/
+-- react-switchery@1.1.3 
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
+-- react-tag-input@4.7.2 
npm ERR!     npm bugs react-bootstrap-select
+-- react-toggle-switch@2.1.4 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
+-- select2@4.0.3 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls react-bootstrap-select
+-- shallow-equal-fuzzy@0.0.2 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
`-- url-loader@0.5.8 


npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\7.4.0\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.9.5\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
npm ERR!     D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
'jsx' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\nnpm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:\r\nnpm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.2\r\nnpm WARN react-addons-test-utils@15.6.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.4.2 but none was installed.\r\nnpm WARN react-native@0.39.2 requires a peer of react@~15.4.0-rc.4 but none was installed.\r\nnpm WARN tessact@0.0.1 No repository field.\r\nnpm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200\r\nnpm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\7.4.0\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\3.9.5\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"\r\nnpm ERR! node v7.4.0\r\nnpm ERR! npm  v3.9.5\r\nnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE\r\n\r\nnpm ERR! react-bootstrap-select@0.14.0 postinstall: `jsx jsx/ dist/`\r\nnpm ERR! Exit status 1\r\nnpm ERR! \r\nnpm ERR! Failed at the react-bootstrap-select@0.14.0 postinstall script 'jsx jsx/ dist/'.\r\nnpm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.\r\nnpm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the react-bootstrap-select package,\r\nnpm ERR! not with npm itself.\r\nnpm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:\r\nnpm ERR!     jsx jsx/ dist/\r\nnpm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:\r\nnpm ERR!     npm bugs react-bootstrap-select\r\nnpm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:\r\nnpm ERR!     npm owner ls react-bootstrap-select\r\nnpm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.\r\n\r\nnpm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:\r\nnpm ERR!     D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\65.60827.2986\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

I tried runnig npm install but that too didn't make any difference. Earlier I deployed the app and it was successful. How can I solve it?

Comment: Looks like failure relates to missing jsx. That should give you a direction to investigate.

Comment: I am still struggling

Comment: And my code is running fine on localhost

Answer (score 1):

> 'jsx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The error is self-explaining. You first need to install JSX compiler toolkit when you build your react app on the remote server. 
On Azure Web App, you can install it with the following command in Kudu Console (`https://<your-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`).

```
npm install -g jsx
```

Comment: No help. I tried this. Still when I redeploy it gives same error.